# Installing GUI on top of CLI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

How do you start the GUI client (beta) when you already have the CLI wallet installed? Do you add it to the same folder?

I'm using Windows 10. Of course I can just try it, but I'd like to know what the recommended procedure is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is extract the .zip to some folder and run `monero-wallet-gui.exe`. In case the GUI window is looking strange or not displayed, run `start-low-graphics-mode.bat`.

If you're already running `monerod` manually, it will connect to it. If you're not running `monerod`, the GUI will start it itself in the background (using the default %programdata% folder where to look for blockchain data).

You can simultaneously have the CLI and GUI open, and they will both talk to the same daemon. Just don't open the same wallet with both, unless you're opening a copy of wallet files.

Comment: Can you use the same wallet with both but just not simultaneously?

Comment: Sure, close one, open from the other one.